# Laravel Validator::validateDecimal does not exist

Tags: request, laravel-9

I don't know how this error could happen because I am running laravel 9.28.0 which does have the validateDecimal validator and it is not a custom validator.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-decimal

here is my request:

```
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class FairlingoOmzetRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'omzet' => [
                'required',
                'decimal:2',
                'min:0',
            ],
            'aantal_opdrachten' => [
                'required',
                'min:0',
                'int'
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

I have tried looking for a solution on the internet but there was none.

Full error:

https://flareapp.io/share/bP98rqDm#F2

Answer (score 5):

For some reason not all Versions of Laravel 9 include this validator, if possible the solution would be to upgrade your laravel/framework dependency to a later one.

I did the upgrade to the latest version with composer:

```
composer update laravel/framework:9.49.0
```

In my case i was on version [9.38.0](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v9.38.0/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L277) and as you can see in their repo they don't have that validator but [9.49.0](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v9.49.0/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L282) does.